# Can I install a volume licensed version of Windows 10 Education on an unlicensed Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

My wife is a student and she will be getting a volume licensed version of Windows 10 Education for free.

We are buying a her a laptop with a [good config](https://www.campuspoint.de/21a1s00e00-lenovocampus-thinkpad-p14s-g2-amd.html) but no OS installed.

My plan is to:

1. [Download an ISO version](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10ISO) of Windows 10
2. Put the image on a USB
3. Install in the new laptop
4. Then somehow (don't have the instructions from Uni yet) install the
   volume licensed Windows 10 Education on this unlicensed version of Windows

I assume this should work but I just want to make sure before we buy this laptop.

1. Can someone please confirm the feasibility of this approach?
2. Any caveats/risks/concerns I should watch out for?

Comment: You need to install the Education Version directly on the machine that will use the Education version.

Comment: The ISO you linked to does not include Enterprise or Education. You will have to download the appropriate ISO from the school directly. Once you have the instructions you should [edit] this question and tell us what step you are specifically stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Media Creation Tool only offers Windows 10 Home or Pro,
which cannot be activated by a Windows 10 Education Key.

Your institution might provide you with the Education edition of Windows 10.

If you are only provided with a license (product key), you can download
the ISO file from the Microsoft Download Academic Products website
at the following address:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/vlacademicISO

In any case, you need to get from the university either the ISO
*and* product key, or at least the product key alone.